# WinAppDriver server arguments

Tags: appium, appium-desktop

My end goal is to enable the "execute_driver_script" feature in the WinAppDriver server as documented here: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/security.md

The problem I am running into is attempting to pass in the --driver-args argument documented here: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/server-args.md. I feel like I'm doing something really dumb and someone will probably see my mistake immediately. I made a json file that has my CLI arguments but when I make the following command `WinAppDriver.exe --driver-args "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Application Driver\driver_args.json"` in CMD, the application immediately crashes.

My JSON file is formatted as follows:

> {   "address": "10.28.1.147",   "allow-insecure":
> "execute_driver_script",   "base-path": "/wd/hub",   "port": "4723" }

Please, any assistance in this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share the script for this issue reproduction and complete crash logs as observed?

Comment: @BipinKumarChaurasia So it's not a script that I am having a problem with, I am trying to start the WinAppDriver server using the "execute_driver_script' argument which will enable me to run PowerShell scripts.